# How can I scroll through multiple views?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I have multiple views as subclasses of a UIScrollView. I would like to be able to horizontally scroll through those views **using page control**. What is the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are they subclasses of a UIScrollView because you need to scroll within each of the subviews or did you make them subclasses of UIScrollView so that you could scroll between them like you describe in the question?

Comment: I made them subsclasses so I could scroll through them.

Comment: No u have to put then into a uiscrollview, they don't need to be uiscrollviews unless u want to scroll through their content

Answer (score 1):

You don't need for your views to be subclasses of UIScrollView.  UIScrollView is a container that allows scrolling of its contents.

Add all your views as subviews to a single UIScrollView.  Adjust the contentSize property of the scroll view to be large enough to hold all of your views.  Then just add the scrollview to your main view.  Take a look at the documentation of the UIScrollView and make sure that you have all of the features enabled that you want.  (such as scrolling).

Comment: What about page control? Can I do that easily?

Comment: Kind of.  If you want to skip to any subview you can set the scroll offset to its frame origin.

Comment: Yes, page control is simple.  Just turn on pagingEnabled for the scrollView.  It will then scroll in increments of the scroll view's bounds.